# How did this project manage to scam and withdraw staked assets directly into their wallet?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, binance-smart-chain

There's this DEFI project which was running fine for about a month and then 24 hours ago they've managed to somehow transfer withdrawals directly into their devaddress. The smart contract looks normal and the withdrawal function + parameters look okay.

Transaction example 1 (Before Scam - funds went to caller's address):
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe51cc0958f66966ce2f6d9aab659a418aa949adb7b9cb82207f7041c543fa0ec

Transaction example 2 (Scam - funds went to devaddress):
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x19d62e850b39dd45bf101b536ab01797f79854c8914966b5856ac7804da4a8e9

So how did they manage to achieve this?

```
// Withdraw LP tokens from MasterChef.
function withdraw(uint256 _pid, uint256 _amount) public {
    PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];
    UserInfo storage user = userInfo[_pid][msg.sender];
    require(user.amount >= _amount, "withdraw: not good");
    updatePool(_pid);
    uint256 pending = user.amount.mul(pool.accSushiPerShare).div(1e12).sub(user.rewardDebt);
    if(pending > 0) {
        safeSushiTransfer(msg.sender, pending);
    }
    if(_amount > 0) {
        user.amount = user.amount.sub(_amount);

        // pid0 token, pid1 pair 0% fee, other token 5% fee
        uint256 buybackAmount = _amount.mul(50).div(1000);
        // transfer to treasury contract and buyback token.
        if (_pid > 1 && buybackAmount > 0) {
            pool.lpToken.safeTransfer(devaddr, buybackAmount);
            _amount = _amount.sub(buybackAmount);
        }
        pool.lpToken.safeTransfer(address(msg.sender), _amount);
    }
    user.rewardDebt = user.amount.mul(pool.accSushiPerShare).div(1e12);
    emit Withdraw(msg.sender, _pid, _amount);
}
```

Comment: Welcome at SO, but even with source code included, I suggest to consider the [Information Security stack exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Funny that site you link to contains 
> Questions about specific cryptocurrencies may be best answered on their respective sites; Bitcoin, Ethereum, Monero, Iota, or Stellar. 
So i guess maybe https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/